# Quran Recitation In Digital form

Tags: wudu, quran-recitation

Is it allowed to recite or Listen Quran in the digital(On leptop or mobile pdf's or mp3's) form without Wudu?

Comment: That does not clearify my full question

Answer (score 0):

> Narrated 'Aisha: "**The Prophet used to recite the Quran with his head in my lap while I used to be in my periods** (having menses).  (Translation of Sahih Bukhari, ONENESS, UNIQUENESS OF ALLAH (TAWHEED), Volume 9, Book 93, Number 639)

So, I guess the above hadith clearly answers your question. And in fact it answers in general to this...

> Can we listen to Qur'an without wudu?

As, in the hadith, Ayesha(RA) was listening to Qur'an in a state far worse from not being in a state of wudu while the Prophet(pbuh) is witnessing.

May the creator guide us all.